# How come my bar graph is not showing in my matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, missing-features

I can't seem to get my bar graph plotted and there is no error message.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv('report.csv')
df['Income'] = df['Income'].astype(int)
avgincome = df.groupby('Education')['Income'].mean()
eduyear = avgincome.index
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.style.use('tableau-colorblind10')
plt.barh( eduyear,avgincome, align='center')
plt.title('Average Income by Years of Education', fontsize = 20)
plt.xlabel('Years', fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel('Avg Income', fontsize = 15)
plt.xlim(left=0,right=25)
plt.ylim(bottom=0,top=90000)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is the output I got. I managed to get the chart without the bars. Does anyone know what went wrong with my code?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kZ-0qtexzdRtfRenWiYBk3N1a8keyIdF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: are you running this in a notebook or a console?

Comment: Remove the `plt.ylim` command

Comment: you're plotting your bars, horizontally along the y-axis, and then setting your y-limit to 90,000.

Comment: You can also just do `avgincome.plot.barh()`.

Comment: I have amended the axis to:
`# Set ranges for the x-axis and y-axis
plt.ylim(left=0,right=90000)
plt.xlim(bottom=0,top=25)`. The axis looks ok now.

Comment: But this error shows up:`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-595e2ca95ad2> in <module>
     22 
     23 # Set ranges for the x-axis and y-axis
---> 24 plt.ylim(left=0,right=90000)
     25 plt.xlim(bottom=0,top=25)
     26 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in ylim(*args, **kwargs)
   1431     if not args and not kwargs:
   1432         return ax.get_ylim()
-> 1433     ret = ax.set_ylim(*args, **kwargs)
   1434     return ret
   1435 

TypeError: set_ylim() got an unexpected keyword argument 'left'`

Comment: I managed to clear the error by removing both x and y-axis parameters. Thank you!